# How to use JSON in MonetDB

Tags: json, monetdb

MonetDB documentation says, that JSON is supported in MonetDB, but I can`t find any example.
When I try to implement this query in MonetDB client:

```
   json.filter({ "store": {    
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }}},'$')
```

I get this error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT in: "json"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.monetdb.org/pipermail/users-list/2014-November/007700.html:

In MonetDB, JSON is a column type, so you first need to define a table with a column of type JSON, something like:

`CREATE TABLE a (js JSON);`

Once you inserted JSON documents into the table, you can do a query like:

`SELECT json.filter(js, 'store') FROM a;`

Comment: Thanks, the most important part is: "build it from source", because I used win version, that did not support json.

Comment: Can I use JSON type as a UDF input parameter? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting single quotes around the first param?

The following works for me.

```
select json.filter('{ "store": {
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }}}', '$');
```

The result is:

```
[{ "store": {
"bicycle": {
  "color": "red",
  "price": 19.95
}}}]
```

I also tried this:

```
select json.filter('{ "store": {
  "bicycle": {
    "color": "red",
    "price": 19.95
  }}}', '$.store.bicycle.color');
```

The result is:

```
["red"]
```

To return the colour as a string:

```
select json.text(json.filter('{ "store": {
  "bicycle": {
    "color": "red",
    "price": 19.95
  }}}', '$.store.bicycle.color'));
```

...I get:

```
red
```

If I try:

```
select json.text(json.filter('{ "store": {
  "bicycle": {
    "color": "red",
    "price": 19.95
  }}}', '$.store.bicycle.price'));
```

...I get back the price as a string:

```
19.95
```

But I can also get it back as a number:

```
select json.number(json.filter('{ "store": {
      "bicycle": {
        "color": "red",
        "price": 19.95
      }}}', '$.store.bicycle.price'));
```